# Can we deduce that $⌊r^{n}α⌋≃r^{n}α$ when $r→∞$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, irrational-numbers, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $α∈(0,1)$ be an irrational number and let $n≥1$ be a fixed positive integer. For any $r>4$ we define the positive integer $$k=⌊r^{n}α⌋$$ where $⌊.⌋$ denotes the floor function.

My **question** is: Can we deduce that $$⌊r^{n}α⌋≃r^{n}α$$ when $r→∞$? (They have the same order of magnitude)

Comment: What do you mean with $≃$ here?

Comment: My guess would be $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor r^n\alpha\rfloor}{r^n\alpha} = 1$?

Comment: @Wojowu: They have the same order of magnitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because
$$1-\frac{1}{r^n\alpha}<\frac{\lfloor r^n \alpha\rfloor}{r^n\alpha}\leq 1$$